# Loading an external widget in widgets-config.xml

Tags: widget, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am unable to load an iWidget externally on the communities page
This is my widget def:

```
<widgetDef defId="qmiWidget" primaryWidget="false" modes="view fullpage edit search"  
 url="http://questionmine.com/app1/widgets/index/publishProject_iWidget"/>
```

But it replaces the http and tries to load it internally

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/communities/ajaxProxy/http/questionmine.com/app1/widgets/index/publishProject_iWidget"
```

Any idea how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Since your widget resides on another domain, you have to configure the "Ajax Proxy" to allow this.

Take a look at this here:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Configuring_the_AJAX_proxy_ic45&content=pdcontent

For testing purposes (ONLY testing) it would be safe to allow "*" but for a production environment it is strongly advised to be more specific, in your case something like "questionmine.com/app1/*"

You can even configure specific proxy rules per application (Communities, Profiles, Homepage,...)
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Configuring_the_AJAX_proxy_for_a_specific_application_ic45&content=pdcontent

BTW: If you ever tried to enable feeds in a community, the same applies. Without further configuration, only same-domain feeds would be allowed.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I got another problem now. For some reason after the widget loads it goes into a refresh loop. I commented all my js, forms even the css but no luck.

Comment: If you could post your widget and elaborate a bit on your context (preferably in a new question posting) I'm sure there's gonna be a solution. ;)

Comment: @user2400780 - Did you ever find the cause of the reloading issue mentioned here? I have encountered this in a few clients' systems but cannot replicate locally nor find a fix.